# Tkinter Entry .get from a definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I keep getting a none Type attribute error and idk how to fix it as i looked on many videos and none helped. i don't know what I'm doing wrong. any help is appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *

def find():
    user = whiteBox.get()
    print(user)
root = Tk()
weatherResult = StringVar()
weatherResult.set("Enter a Place")

weather = Label(root, textvariable=weatherResult).pack()
whiteBox = Entry(root).pack()
check = Button(root, text="find", command=find).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it helped you? You can accept another answer later if it is better than mine.

Comment: @10Rep it seems like the only right answer :D

Comment: @Atlas435 Ya :). But I'm just saying in case there is another answer that comes along with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a very common mistake. The value of your widget will be a `NoneType`, because you are using `.pack` on the same line.

So, your code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def find():
    user = whiteBox.get()
    print(user)
root = Tk()
weatherResult = StringVar()
weatherResult.set("Enter a Place")

weather = Label(root, textvariable=weatherResult).pack()
whiteBox = Entry(root)
whiteBox.pack()
check = Button(root, text="find", command=find).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This should be the result you want. Hope this helps!